# How to change source and load media player with youtube video?

Tags: mediaelement.js

I am trying to build a playlist and when the first video ends, i am changing the source and calling calling load. This doesnt work for me in html5 mode. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The youtube pluginApi's setSrc method doesn't exist or is incorrect: https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/381

You'll either have to directly call loadVideoByUrl() or loadVideoById() from within the pluginApi:

```
var myVideoPlayer = new MediaElementPlayer('#elementId');
myVideoPlayer.media.pluginApi.loadVideoById('myYoutubeId');
```

Or create a plugin that will extend the "media" index and add setSrc() to call one of those methods:

```
/* global mejs */

(function($) {
    $.extend(MediaElementPlayer.prototype, {
        buildmyyoutube: function(player, controls, layers, media) {
            if (!player.isVideo || media.pluginType !== 'youtube') {
                return;
            }

            $.extend(media, {
                /**
                 * mejs' youtube plugin's setSrc doesn't support youtube urls (the flash one does)
                 * 
                 * @param string urlOrId Can either be a youtube url http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<YoutubeId>
                 *                       or directly a youtube id
                 */
                setSrc: function (urlOrId) {
                    var queryStr = urlOrId.match(/v=([^&]*)/);
                    var id = urlOrId;

                    if(queryStr !== null) {
                        id = queryStr[1];
                    }
                    this.pluginApi.loadVideoById(id);
                }
            });
        }
    });
})(mejs.$);

var myVideoPlayer = new MediaElementPlayer('#elementId', {features: ['myyoutube']});
myVideoPlayer.setSrc('myYoutubeId');
myVideoPlayer.setSrc('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myYoutubeId');
```

I haven't tested it as is, I had to edit it out from some code I use, but it should work.