# Mediaelement - regarding VAST and Playlists

Tags: mediaelement.js

I'm using Mediaelement.js and trying to figure out a way to create a playlist that plays videos with a VAST ad in between each video on the playlist.

I've identified this plugin to help:
https://github.com/duozersk/mep-feature-playlist

Also, I would love to slide Youtube videos in there as the "source", however there is apparently an error reported on Github here: https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/910

Anyone have any ideas on the tweaks needed for this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be the same bug from the YouTube plugin as is described here: [How to change source and load media player with youtube video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387940/how-to-change-source-and-load-media-player-with-youtube-video/17066259#17066259)